# Git rebase duplicates functions

Tags: git, rebase

I am pretty new to Git, and I can't find anything like what I am seeing, so I figure maybe I am just doing something wrong.

I am trying to rebase the branch onto master so that the branch has the latest commits from master, so I can test it before a final merge.

Here is the workflow I am following:

```
> git clone <master>
> git remote add branch_repo <branch>
> git fetch branch_repo
> git checkout -b new_branch branch_repo/branch
> git fetch origin
> git rebase origin/master
```

Other important information:

- This branch has several significant changes throughout the code base
- Master has been refactored at least once since the initial branch

The result is, after the rebase completes, and I resolve all merge conflicts, the resulting files have many duplicate functions. Sometimes the auto-merge makes no sense to me - like the body of one function is placed with the declaration of a completely different function.

Is my workflow wrong, or is this just the unfortunate by-product of a refactor+ major revision which must be resolved manually?

Comment: Could you just tell what you are trying to accomplish here? You already have a master branch and you want to create a new_branch on top of master and add stuff to it?

Comment: And you don't clone a branch, you clone a repo

Comment: Tried to add some more context - I am trying to bring the branch up to speed so it has all the Master commits, so it can be tested properly.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so if I understand the situation correct, this is how it is. You branched off master, made some changes but before you could push your changes to master, someone else updated master. So now you have to rebase off master so that you get the new changes been made to master. Well here is how you do it. You were not totally wrong.

```
(Assuming you are in you branch)

1. > git checkout master
2. > git pull (assuming your remote points to origin/master)
3. > git checkout your_branch (assuming there were no merge conflicts during the pull)
4. > git rebase -i master (now that your local master is up to date you can rebase off it)
```

Sort out the merge conflicts and you should be good to go.

Comment: Thanks! somehow the interactive flag helped. I think one of the merges was just screwy (I had to manually remove a lot of duplicate content - but it was obvious this time through)